# How to make sure the partial rederend by @Html.Action will be complete before $(document).ready(function () {})?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How to make sure the partial rederend by @Html.Action will be completely rendered before $(document).ready(function () {}) is fired ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will of course be rendered before any client-side javascript runs in the `ready` function because `@Html.Action()` renders on the *server side*.  (And `ready` runs after the document from the server has finished loading.)